# Lost type in PyTorch optimization

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, gradient, gradient-descent

I'm trying to implement a simple minimizer in PyTorch, here is the code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print('i =', i, ' q =', q)
    v_trans = transform_dq(v, q)
    loss = mse(v_trans, v_target)
    loss.backward()
    q = q - eta * q.grad

print('Final q = ', q)
```

Where v and q are tensors, and eta = 0.01.

The problem is that at the line `q = q - eta * q.grad` I get an error on the second iteration of the loop:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

It looks like the update for q changes the graph in an unwanted way (q is not a leaf of the graph anymore and hence it doesn't have a grad). If that is the case, then how to implement this simple minimizer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to reset `q`'s gradients before each iteration.
Second, you should update `q` outside "gradient scope":

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    q = q - eta * q.grad
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How do I reset the gradients?

Comment: @Notin_sensus try `q.grad = None`